# how python3 decode() knows how to delimit the code points?

Tags: python, utf-8

How does the python3 decode() function knows how to delimit the hexs from each other given there is no delimiter contained in a byte string right?
Do b-strings have delimiters under the hood?

Utf-8 encoded character may be a 1-B up to 4-B long, that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The high bits of the first byte of a character inform the byte length of the character. See about [UTF-8 in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding). Basically, if the first byte is

- `0xxxxxxx`: it is a 1-byte character
- `110xxxxx`: it is a 2-byte character
- `1110xxxx`: it is a 3-byte character
- `11110xxx`: it is a 4-byte character

Comment: That's so simple!